# Find sum of 2 largest numbers in a list of integers

Tags: c#

In c#, Need to pick the max value in the array and sum it to the next least value.

Expected output is 5+4

Tried couple of syntax in the `foreach`, i couldn't get the exact output. looking for some help

```
int[] arr =new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};

foreach (int i in arr)
{

}
```

Comment: What is `predecessor`? Where is sum? What is expected result? If you cannot get exact output, then what output you have?

Comment: 4 votes for closing. I mentioned to say value 4 inside the array. Expected output is 4+5

Comment: You may want to ask it on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ as there is no clear reason why one would use `foreach` for the task.

Comment: He wants to find the largest element in the array and sum it with the preceding element. I'd probably use LINQ for this.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov , i am sorry . i might be wrong. If there is a correctapproach, please help me in getting the syntax

Comment: @goofyui what if arr is `{1,2,5,4,3}`? Expected result is 2+5 or still 4+5?

Comment: @goofyui do you want to nearest value by value or position ?

Comment: goofyui, I've changed title - please make sure it matches your intent so question can be considered for re-opening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some LINQ like following should solve it:

```
arr.OrderByDescending(z=>z).Take(2).Sum()
```

Note that sorting is slow, you may actually want to find Max twice instead...

Comment: doh! you beat me to it :)

Comment: Ahh.. the beauty of LINQ... makes one feel thankful for making a living programming in C#.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = (from x in arr orderby x descending select x).Take(2).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int max = arr[0];
        int index = -1;
        int total=0;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > max)
            {
                max = arr[i];
                index = i;
            }

        }
        if(index != -1) //if you have predecessor
        total = max+arr[index-1];
        else            //if you don't have predecessor
        total = max;
```